# Business API: sharing_info object not returned for in /files/list_folder

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying to retrieve "share information" of a file that is contained inside user  folder in a team space.
Basically, sharing a file using links from the user folder, I would like to understand if a file has been shared or not.
The folder containing the file shared is not shared itself.

The documentation states that:

> The access rights of the content is returned within the sharing_info of the file metadata.
>   [...]
>   The absence of sharing_info on a file or folder indicates that it is unshared content, accessible only by the user.

I used the followin API to retrieve user file and folder list:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Dropbox-API-Select-User: <user-id>' \
  -d '{"path": "","recursive": true,"include_media_info": false,"include_deleted": false,"include_has_explicit_shared_members": true,"include_mounted_folders": true, "limit":2000}'
```

The response do not contain sharing_info but inside dropbox the sharing settings are set to link with access to anyone (see picture)
[image: picture of a shared file]

There is any way to understand, using the **files/list_folder** API, if a file has been shared using a link? If not, which API should I use to discern this case? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to retrieve shared links along with the file listing. The `sharing_info` there is only for the the shared folder kind of sharing, not shared links. I'll pass this along as a feature request. I can't promise if or when that might be implemented though.

Instead, if you want to retrieve shared links for any particular item, you should use [/2/sharing/list_shared_links](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_shared_links).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Greg, at the moment it would be useful for me to know even just if it has been shared or not. I have 2 question then: 
there is any chance to know if and when this feature might be implemented?
Does the batch request for list_shared_links exist?

Comment: I'll make a note to follow up on this thread if/when this is implemented. If you call /2/sharing/list_shared_links with no `path`, it will return all shared links (though you may need to take the returned `cursor`, if given, and call back to get more if there are many).

Comment: Thanks Greg.
What do you exactly mean "no `path`"? 
I tried to send `{"path": ""}` and I got:
> Error in call to API function "sharing/list_shared_links": request body: path: The root folder is unsupported.
Then I tried with empty body but I got a generic 500 error.
Also adding `Dropbox-API-Path-Root`, pointing to the private member space, does not work.

Comment: @verodigiorgio By "no `path`" I meant omitting the `path` parameter entirely. It sounds like you just tried that though, and got a 500 error. Please report that here, including the `x-dropbox-request-id` response header value, so we can look into it for you: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is this requires two calls to the API.